# Does Beta by Crashlytics Support iOS's On-Demand Resources?

Tags: ios, google-fabric, on-demand-resources

I am fairly certain that the answer to this question is "No", but I am asking anyway. My evidence that Beta by Crashlytics does not support iOS's on-demand-resources is an app build that works fine when downloaded from TestFlight, but throws the following iOS error when downloaded from Beta:

> Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 4994 “The requested
>   application data doesn’t exist.” UserInfo = {
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason = Request code not be completed. Invalid tag in set ‘{(cardImage, cardAudio)}.’ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received confirmation from Fabric that they currently "don't support apps via Beta using on-demand resources."